# AIX 7 - Command To Check Histsize Is Set Correctly For All Users

Tags: scripting, users, password, aix

I am checking to see if the minimum password history setting is set to 6.

Using the command below, I am able to check the default stanza:

```
lssec -f /etc/security/user -s default -a histsize
```

Can this command be enhanced to view all user settings to ensure it is set to 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [lssec](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=l-lssec-command)'s `-s` option only accepts the string "default" or one specific user, use [lsuser](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=l-lsuser-command) to list every user and their histsize attribute, then use awk to look for values other than 6:

```
lsuser -C -a histsize ALL | awk -F: 'NR > 1 && $2 != 6'
```

The "NR > 1" portion skips the header line; the default action is to print the entire line, which would show the username and their histsize attribute.